# Pass C# Array To Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, arrays

What is the best way to pass C# array to javascript variable ?

I have sample code but this return character by character from C# array, I want to return in normal way like word by word in javascript array;

C# code behind:

```
 public string[] names = { "John", "Pesho", "Maria"};
 public JavaScriptSerializer javaSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

javascript code:

```
 <script>
    var a = '<%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.names) %>';
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        console.log(a[i]);
    }
 </script>
```

This script return all words from "names" array in single char array . I want to return in normal way like ["John"] ["Pesho"] ...

**What is the best way to pass C# array to javascript ?**

When I run this code I get the following in console of Chrome browser:

```
[ Profile.aspx:44
" Profile.aspx:44
v Profile.aspx:44
a Profile.aspx:44
l Profile.aspx:44
e Profile.aspx:44
r Profile.aspx:44
i Profile.aspx:44
" Profile.aspx:44
, Profile.aspx:44
" Profile.aspx:44
p Profile.aspx:44
e Profile.aspx:44
s Profile.aspx:44
h Profile.aspx:44
o Profile.aspx:44
" Profile.aspx:44
, Profile.aspx:44
" Profile.aspx:44
m Profile.aspx:44
a Profile.aspx:44
r Profile.aspx:44
i Profile.aspx:44
a Profile.aspx:44
" Profile.aspx:44
]
```

Comment: Do you mean a single array of strings, like `["John", "Pesho", "Maria"]` ?

Comment: I want "a" variable to be equal to C# "names" array

Comment: "This script return all words from "names" array in single char array"... can you show us what gets rendered?

Comment: don't put quotes around it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
var a = '<%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.names) %>';
```

with

```
var a = <%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.names) %>;
```

You were putting the resulting JSON into a javascript string, which would result in your example output iterating through each character of the `Serialize` call.

Comment: One more question. I see that  "this.javaSerial.Serialize" return string. How this "var a" accept array ?

Comment: It returns a `C#` string, when you do `<%= ... %>` asp.net will output the contents of the string to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

your c# code will return a string, you have to first parse the string using JSON.parse, and then iterate through it:

```
var a = JSON.parse('<%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.names) %>');
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    console.log(a[i]);
}
```

or maybe as @Matthew said, don't put quotes around it, so you won't have to parse it.