# passing c# array to java script

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

I have an array in my page_load in c# which i want to access in java script but don't know how to do that..

```
float [] energyArray = new float[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    energyArray[i] = energyObj[i].FwdHr;
}
```

Now i want to access in javascript in place of data-

```
series: [{
    name: 'Tokyo',
    data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]
}]
```

Comment: You could store the series as a string in a HiddenField then split it up in the javascript

Comment: you might using it for displaying high chart i guess,  i normally use this in .cs page....
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "abc", stringARRAY );

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A very easy way is to use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) class to transform your C# object into JSON:

**C#**

```
float [] energyArray = new float[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
   {
       energyArray[i] = energyObj[i].FwdHr;
   }
```

**Javascript:**

```
var dataArray = <%=new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(energyArray);%>;
var series = [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: dataArray
        }];
```

Comment: where is javascript serializer.. to import it?? @Blade0rz

Comment: From the linked MSDN page: System.Web.Extensions (in System.Web.Extensions.dll)

Comment: not getting it.. do you know where to change target framework in vs2010?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4520569/where-can-i-find-the-assembly-system-web-extensions-dll

Comment: thanks but what to do about error - javascriptSerializer not found? should i include it in javascript but how?

Comment: You need to include the System.Web.Extensions dll in your project references as per this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30898/discussion-between-inderpal-singh-and-blade0rz)

Answer (score 3):

Changing your problem a little bit here...

Instead of manipulating an already existing script, consider constructing the whole javascript string block and then use `Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx

```
int[] yourArray = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
string arrElements = string.Join(",", yourArray.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray());
string strJs = string.Format("var yourArray=[{0}]", arrElements);
RegisterClientScriptBlock("Test", strJs);
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to pass the array to the client side (tha javascript part) somehow:

I would suggest making an ajax request to a page, that would return the serialized array or as @Blade0rz suggested, to output the serialized string directly to the page. to serialize the array to a JSON format you would call the methods of the JavaScriptSerializer  class:

more on it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb337495.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**C# code behind:**

```
float [] energyArray = new float[count];
 public JavaScriptSerializer javaSerial = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

**Try This Code:**

```
<script>
var a = <%= this.javaSerial.Serialize(this.energyArray) %>;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        console.log(a[i]);
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: `javaSerial` is not a C# function

Comment: Because `javaSerial` is not a C# function and you are calling it in C# -- this won't compile.

Comment: @Hogan Refer this question and answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14942385/pass-c-sharp-array-to-javascript

Comment: That code has nothing to do with this answer, if you want to include all the code there then it might be a correct answer, but as it stands this answer is wrong and gets -1.  Fix it and I will remove the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a HiddenField

```
    <asp:HiddenField id="myHiddenField" runat="server"
```

Set it's value to your array.Tostring() in the code behind
Then in your javascript

```
    var h = document.getElementById('myHiddenField');
    //Should give you an array of strings that you can cast to integers
```