# How to access a c# array from javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET webform web application and 
I defined an array in codebehind and I want to access it in my page by javascript

```
public int[] GetSomeArray()
{
    int[] Labels;
    Labels = new int[8];
    Labels[0] = 100;
    Labels[1] = 90;
    Labels[2] = 111;
    Labels[3] = 121;
    Labels[4] = 81;
    Labels[5] = 102;
    Labels[6] = 93;
    Labels[7] = 103;

    return Labels;
}
```

How can I access these values in javascript code?

Comment: What you are trying to do? You can send it via `jquery ajax` though.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/  Have a read of the documentation and then try figure it out. People on here don't like writing code for you, just helping you sort issues in code you have already written

Comment: @user2399248 Can this Labels be an Enum? like `public enum Label
    {
        Label100 = 100,
        Label90 = 90,
        Label111 = 111,
        Label121 = 121,
        Label81 = 81,
        Label102 = 102,
        Label93 = 93,
        Label103 = 103
    
    }`

otherwise you have to get the data from ajax or in viewmodel

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16833679/3583859 Simply serialize it

Answer (score 1):

Modify function as follows

```
    public string GetSomeArray()
        {
            int[] Labels;
            Labels = new int[8];
            Labels[0] = 100;
            Labels[1] = 90;
            Labels[2] = 111;
            Labels[3] = 121;
            Labels[4] = 81;
            Labels[5] = 102;
            Labels[6] = 93;
            Labels[7] = 103;

            JavaScriptSerializer j = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return j.Serialize(Labels);
}
```

and also on page add

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         var array = <%= GetSomeArray() %>;
</script>
```